# JavaScript problems with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm trying to make some JavaScript actions work in Internet Explorer but so far they aren't working.

The script uses the `id` atrribute to load a page associated to it. For example: `id="4"` will be used to look up the value of the page `getinfo.php?vid=4` and uses the value of this page to change something on the site.

```
function btcd() {
var id;
$('.btcd').each(function(i) {
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.replace('v','');
    $(this).load('js/timeleft.php?vid='+id);
});
$('.btp').each(function(i) {
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.replace('z','');
    $(this).load('js/price.php?vid='+id);
});
$('.button_bied_nu').each(function(i) {
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.replace('b','');
    $.get('js/you.php?vid='+id, function(data){
        var res = data.split(' ');
        if(res[1] == '1') {
            $('#b'+res[0]).css('background-image','url(images/button_bied_nu_you.png)');
        }else{
            $('#b'+res[0]).css('background-image','url(images/button_bied_nu.png)');
        }
    });

});

var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMilliseconds();
setTimeout("btcd()",(900-n));
}
```

The HTML part:

```
<div class="veilingen">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box_top">
            <h3><span class="btcd" id="v1" style="float:right;margin-right:10px">202:50:09</span>Testveiling</h3>
        </div>
    <div class="box_bg">
        <div class="box_image">
            <img src="images/veilingen/test.png" alt="Afbeelding" />
            <br />
            <div class="veiling_lint">
                <b>&euro;<span class="btp" id="z1">36</span></b>
                <span style="font-size:8pt;">(Elk bod verhoogt de prijs met &euro;1)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" onclick="bied(1);" class="button_bied_nu" id="b1">BIED NU!</a><br />
        Klik <a href="?vid=1">hier</a> voor meer informatie over deze veiling.
    </div>
    <div class="box_bottom"></div>
</div>
```

The page itself: http://project.browsertech.nl/001/index.php

Comment: Could you possibly post some of the HTML mark-up? I would first recommend ensuring that all elements have `unique` IDs. This is the recommended practice, and I have had experiences with jQuery and IE where this has caused problems.

Comment: Show the markup as well, so people can see the `id` values. I'm not seeing any obvious errors in the code. (BTW, there's never any need to do `$(this).attr('id')`; `this.id` works universally. Similarly, rather than `setTimeout('btcd();',(900-n))` you can -- and should, in this case -- use `setTimeout(btcd,(900-n))`. E.g., pass a function reference, not a string, into `setTimeout`.)

Comment: Added the html code as requested, and also fixed the thins T.J. Crowder told me, thanks for those.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a successful response for `$.load()`?

Comment: Nope, the whole script just doesn't do a thing in IE, but it works fine in FF, Chrome and Opera (haven't tested any others).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder FireFox doesn't expose the id as global, so it's a good practice to use jquery's attr method.

Comment: @gion_13: Firefox exposes `id` (which is not a global) exactly like every other browser does (and always has), in accordance with the [DOM2 HTML specification Section 1.6.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-63534901). [Gratuitous live proof.](http://jsbin.com/igivuc) :-) Using `attr` for this is completely pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon this is working but caching.
Either use a different ajax call or you could drop this whammy code in:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});
```

Which will stop the load cache (as well as any jQuery ajax call caches)

Comment: Ty, I was halfway through writing a different theory when it clicked! @Seph, glad its working! :)